# Checking Riemann integrability using epsilon definition

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

According to the definition:

> $f$ is $R$ integrable on $[a,c]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f)-L(P,f)< \epsilon $

Here, does the definition say that:
"there is a particular $P$ which makes the statement hold for every $\epsilon$"?
$$OR$$ 
 does the definition mean:
"for any particular $\epsilon$ there is a particular $P$ for which the statement holds"?

Comment: As the $\epsilon$ comes first in the definition, the partition *can* indeed depend on $\varepsilon$. So the second defintion.

Comment: yes, Seems right. Could you tell me if the definition would mean something else, had there been 'all' instead of 'every'?

Comment: All and every are synonyms. It doesn't matter. They are the same thing.